# Is it possible to set a range of array values in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, indexing

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
val grid = Array(10) { IntArray(10) { 1 } }
```

And now I want to set some of them to 2 instead. I could do this:

```
for (i in 0..5) {
    for (j in 0..5) {
        grid[i][j] = 2
    }
}
```

But what I'd like to do is this:

```
grid[0..5][0..5] = 2
```

Is there some faster way to do it like this?

Comment: It seems this is possible for one dimension, by creating an operator function that takes a range (e.g., `operator fun IntArray.set(indices: IntRange, value: Int)`). However, I can't think of how to make this work for a two-dimensional array. Or, at least, I can't think of an intuitive way to do it (you can define the operator function for the two-dimensional array type, but then it _looks like_ you're accessing a one-dimensional array at first glance).

Comment: do you really need arrays? it is probably easier to implement something like that if you do not use arrays (or if you do not mix primitive with ~object arrays)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve something similar, e.g.:

```
grid[3..5, 2..4] = 5
```

by using the following extension function:

```
operator fun Array<IntArray>.set(outerIndices : IntRange, innerIndices : IntRange, newValue : Int) {
    for (i in outerIndices) {
        for (j in innerIndices) {
            this[i][j] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

If you really wanted something like `grid[3..5][2..4] = 5` you would then first need to implement a getter for the first `IntRange` which may hold a ~builder with the actual array reference so that the actual array can be adjusted on the `set`-call.